# Android libreria Gson en Movil no funciona

Tags: android, gson

El problema que tengo es que en mi Aplicación Android estoy utilizando un objeto [gson](/questions/tagged/gson). Me baje las librerías `gson-2.2.4` y en el emulador de eclipse funciona todo perfectamente pero cuando saco la **.apk** y lo pruebo en mi móvil, falla.

Comentando código he visto que falla al crear el objeto Gson.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Tengo puesto estos imports:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
```

¿Alguna idea de porque me falla?¿Me faltará algo?

No se si será que en la apk no se exportan las librerías gson ¿Hay alguna manera de verlo?

Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

El contenido de mi proguard-project.txt:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Comment: en que forma falla, que error muestra? de que forma "sacas" el .apk? te refieres a que lo instalaa, como lo instalas?

Comment: Le doy a exportar proyecto  a "Export Android Aplication" y genero el .apk para instalarlo en el móvil. En el emulador de eclipse funciona bien pero en el móvil da un error y se cierra la aplicación cuando entra en la pantalla donde se crea el objeto gson.

Comment: Ray podrías agregar tu archivo proguard-rules.pro por favor.

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, pero no conozco ese archivo. No lo encuentro, solo veo el proguard-proyect.txt

Comment: revisa en la raiz de tu proyecto, generalmente se usa para agregar opciones de ofuscar u optimizar el còdigo.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/tSHKv.png

Comment: No, no tengo ese archivo. ¿Cómo podría crearlo?¿Podrías pasarme alguna página de manual?

Answer (score 1):

No he tenido problemas usando **Gson**, pero me llamo la atención que no funciona al subir el .apk en un dispositivo físico, por lo tanto en base a una breve búsqueda encontré que existe un problema con la configuración en `proguard` lo cual causa el problema, yo no tuve problemas seguramente porque tengo configurado como lo siguiente dentro de mi archivo proguard.

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
# -keep class mypersonalclass.data.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

Revisa la configuración tomada de: 
https://recalll.co/app/?q=ProGuard%20and%20Gson%20on%20Android%20(ClassCastException)
y
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826171/proguard-for-android-and-gson